# Seamless Integration with REST API

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-filters

Many examples on the net show you how to use `ng-repeat` with in-memory data, but in my case I have long table with infinite scroll that gets data by sending requests to a REST API (scroll down - fetch some data, scroll down again - fetch some more data, etc.). It does work, but I'm wondering how can I integrate that with filters?

Right now I have to call a specific method of API service that makes a request based on text in "search" input box and then controller updates $scope.data.

Is it possible to build a custom filter that would do that? And then my view would be utterly decoupled from the service and I could declaratively tell it how to group and order and filter data, regardless if it's in-memory or comes from a remote server, server that can serve only limited records at a time.

Also later I'm gonna need grouping and ordering as well, I'm so tempted to download the entire dataset and lock parts of the app responsible for grouping, searching and ordering (until all data is on the client), but:

a) that dataset is huge (hundred thousands of records)

b) nobody wants to deal with cache invalidation headaches

c) doing so feels so damn wrong, you don't really expect me to 'keep' all that data in-memory, right?

Can you guys point me to maybe some open-source examples where I can steal some ideas from?

Basically I need to build a service and filters that let me to work with my "pageable" data that comes from api, like it's in memory-data.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how you choose to solve it (there are many ways to infinite-scroll with angular, here is one: http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/), at its latest current beta version, ng-repeat works really **bad** with large amount of data - so do filters. The reason is obvious - pulling so much information for changes is a tuff job. Moreover, ng-repeat by default will re-draw your complete list every time something changes.
There are many solutions you can explore in this area, here are the ones I found productive:

1. http://kamilkp.github.io/angular-vs-repeat/#?tab=8
2. http://www.williambrownstreet.net/blog/2013/07/angularjs-my-solution-to-the-ng-repeat-performance-problem/
3. https://github.com/allaud/quick-ng-repeat

You should also consider the following, which really helps with large amounts of data.

1. https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce

**Updated**
I guess you can't really control your server output, because filtering and ordering large amount of data are better off done on the server side.
I was pointing out the links above since even if you write your own filters (and order-bys), which is quite simple to do - http://jsfiddle.net/gdefpfqL/ - (filter by some company name and then click the "Add More" button - to add more items).
 ordering by is virtually impossible if you can't control the data coming for the server - the only option is getting it all, ordering and then lazy load from the client's memory.
 So if each of your list items doesn't have many binding by it self (as in the example I've added) - the list item is a fairly simple one (for instance: you simply present the results as a plain text in a <li>{{item.name}}</li> then angular ng-repeat might work for you. In this case, filters will work as expected - say you filter by searched text:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchedText"></li>
```

even for **new** items added after the user has searched a text, it will still works because the magic of binding.

Comment: Well, actually my questions addresses somewhat different problem... So let's say you have a 500 items in a list, you can do ordering and filtering easily with angular filters (if that data is in memory). And what if the service gives you only 100 items at a single serve. Then you can't just easily implement filters. So is there a way to build a custom filter that would work in both cases?